# Set AutomationElement visibility or any other property

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-ui-automation

How can I set `IsOffScreen` property for Microsoft UI Automation `AutomationElement` object?

I need to hide automation element.

I was able to find only `TransformPattern` and `Resize` method, but this pattern is not supported by my control (ListView).

Is this possible to acheive at all?
I tried `WPF Inspector` and `Snoop` and both cannot change this text box visibility property. It's readonly.

**update**

Found `Visibility` property in WPF inspector and 'Snoop`(`IsVisible`is readonly, but`Visibility` works), so they both can change element's visibility. Now I know it is possible.

Currently I'm trying to understand how it works. There are source codes available, but it is pretty much big application. Is there anything smaller or any samples available?

Comment: You don't change the visibility of a control through UI Automation. To hide a control you set its `Visibility` to false (in WinForms) or Collapsed/Hidden (in WPF) in code. But sounds like you are trying to control the visibility of a control in another application, which you can't do.

Comment: I can easily do this for windows forms application with WinAPI SendMessage function, but it doesn't work with WPF for obvious reasons. So is there any other way?

Comment: You do realize that even if you *could* do that, it would break the layout?

Comment: Yes, of course. This is not a problem.